# Are dynamic variable names supported?

Tags: go, variables

I was wondering if it is possible to dynamically create variables in Go?

I have provided a pseudo-code below to illustrate what I mean. I am storing the newly created variables in a slice:

```
func method() {
  slice := make([]type)
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    var variable+i=i;
    slice := append(slice, variablei)
  }
}
```

At the end of the loop, the slice should contain the variables: variable1, variable2...variable9

Comment: There's no reason to name your variables `variable1`, `variable2` ... in this example. The variable name is only visible inside the loop anyway. After the loop is finished, you have a slice where you refer to the values you put in it with `slice[0]` for the first variable, slice[1] for the second, and so on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go has no dynamic variables.
Dynamic variables in most languages are implemented as Map (Hashtable).

So you can have one of following maps in your code that will do what you want

```
var m1 map[string]int 
var m2 map[string]string 
var m3 map[string]interface{}
```

here is Go code that does what you what

http://play.golang.org/p/d4aKTi1OB0

```
package main

import "fmt"


func method() []int {
  var  slice []int 
  for i := 0; i < 10; i++  {
    m1 := map[string]int{}
    key := fmt.Sprintf("variable%d", i)
    m1[key] = i
    slice = append(slice, m1[key])
  }
  return slice
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(method())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No; you cannot refer to local variables if you don’t know their names at compile-time.

If you need the extra indirection you can do it using pointers instead.

```
func function() {
    slice := []*int{}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        variable := i
        slice = append(slice, &variable)
    }
    // slice now contains ten pointers to integers
}
```

Also note that the parentheses in the for loop ought to be omitted, and putting the opening brace on a new line is a syntax error due to automatic semicolon insertion after `++`. `make`ing a slice requires you to pass a length, hence I don’t use it since `append` is used anyway.