# Can I use interfaces as dynamic variables?

Tags: go, variables

[Go doesn't have dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147978/are-dynamic-variables-supported).

That said, I would like to know what the variable "a" is, in this program bellow, once I can use it as integer and as string. Even conditionals statements work well with it

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a interface{}
    myInt := 1
    myString := "hi"
    
    a = myInt
    if a == 1 {
        fmt.Println("equals to 1")
    }
    
    a = myString
    if a == "hi" {
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this example will help: https://play.golang.org/p/wjlz9rluakh

Comment: Conditional expressions may work but you can't use it as an int or string. You can't do `a + 1` for example.

Comment: "Can I use interfaces as dynamic variables?" Makes no sense to ask. There are no "dynamic variables" (whatever that may mean) in Go. There is a certain amount of polymorphism in Go 1 and that is done through interface type. Please take the Tour of Go to learn about interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a type switch:

```
package main

func main() {
   var a interface{} = 1

   switch aType := a.(type) {
   case string:
      println("string", aType)
   case int:
      println("int", aType)
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches

Answer (score 1):

To determine what the variable type of 'a' you can make use of `reflect.TypeOf()`,I recreated your code as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var a interface{}
    myInt := 1
    myString := "hi"

    a = myInt
    if a == 1 {
        fmt.Println("equals to 1")
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a))
    }

    a = myString
    if a == "hi" {
        fmt.Println(a)
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
equals to 1
int
hi
string
```